# Combine all bootstrap js and css files?

Tags: html, css, performance

I learned that combining all my js scripts and css files will make my website load faster. When I did that the colors changed and the slider stopped working. I think I may have put my css files in the wrong order, will that effect anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably overrode some of the styles in your first CSS file in your second CSS file, so the order does matter.

For example, if you wrote

```
#id {
    color: green;
}
```

in your first stylesheet and

```
#id {
    color: blue;
}
```

in your second, then `#id` will be blue, not green.

If you switched the first and second stylesheets, then `#id` would be green.

JavaScript is the same.

Comment: THX you explained it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you put the css in the wrong order, that would break the way css classes are overriding other classes and you will get unexpected behavior. You need to combine it exactly in the same order it was previously decelerated.
With javascript the order could also matter, so you should also combine it in exactly the same way it was declared originally in your html.

Answer (score 1):

YES! CSS stands for cascading style sheets.  The cascading part plays a big part in answering your question because order can greatly determine the computed style of your elements. If a matching rule/selector has greater or equal specificity as another above it, the property that comes last will overrule it.  Part of writing good CSS is letting this work to your advantage.